# ASP.NET Core Windows Authentication on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, active-directory, kerberos

I run ASP.NET Core web application in a Linux container. I need to provide Windows authentication for my application. How can this be implemented?

I assume that the problem can be solved using a reverse proxy server that can authenticate via Kerberos.

Answer (score 14):

Starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, it is now possible to use Windows Authentication on Linux and MacOS by adding the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate) NuGet package, and using this in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
```

And this in `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

And some additional configuration that's described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).